# Cursor is returning more data that is available in table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I have query

```
select * from ot.city_vw;
```

The data coming is:
[image]

But when I write a pl/sql block to get the data then

```
declare
v_data OT.city%rowtype;
CURSOR cur1  is
select * from ot.city_vw;
begin

open cur1;
loop
fetch cur1 into v_data;
dbms_output.put_line(v_data.city_id);
dbms_output.put_line(v_data.city_name);
 EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
end;
/
```

the last table data is coming twice as below in picture:

[image]

what is the problem with my cursor? why is the last data coming twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `EXIT` up.

```
open cur1;
loop
  fetch cur1 into v_data;
  EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;                      --> here
  dbms_output.put_line(v_data.city_id);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_data.city_name);
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
```

---

Or, even better, user cursor `FOR` loop:

```
begin
  for v_data in (select * from ot.city_vw) 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_data.city_id);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_data.city_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

Doesn't it look simpler? Oracle does all the *dirty* job for you (declaring a cursor variable, opening the cursor, exiting the loop, closing the cursor). I suggest you use it whenever possible.